# what custom post type this archive belongs to?

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm in the process of making few changes to the header of my secondary pages, but I need to identify whether my page is an archive page, and if it is a CPT archive page or not.

Is there something quick I can use=
Thanks

Comment: You can spit out the post

    `global $post; echo $post->post_type;`

or if you're in a loop you can just say `echo $post->post_type`

Answer (score 2):

The aptly named [`is_post_type_archive()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) seems to be what you need, or perhaps that plus  [`is_archive()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) depending on exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Don't forget `is_home()` for Posts archive.

Comment: What's the point to use the is_home in this context?

Comment: @AndreaMoro : it may or may not be useful. That depends on the context, which you have explained only minimally.